# How can I separate this image into two separate vectors?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, eps

I'm not a graphics illustrator or an artist, and I only have Fireworks CS5.

I purchased [this EPS](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiVhagEJYqS2hW8gEKUQXoFoN3ln?e=eXzkKA) at depositphotos thinking that the road (with the line in the middle) was actually two curved lines. Unfortunately, it's just one vector with the line in the middle.

With Fireworks CS5 I've tried to divide this vector into two vectors (left and right side of road), but I simply don't know how to divide it. I even tried to redraw it with the *Pen tool*, but that was a disaster

Can anyone suggest an easy way to divide this vector into two separate vectors?

Comment: Fireworks isn't a vector image editor. It's raster software.  If you can't afford to buy anything, get Inkscape, it's free. It can open that EPS file just fine.  Not sure what you are trying to do though. The road is a compound path filled white, the lines up the middle are holes, not lines.

Comment: Fireworks is a vector editor @BillyKerr It does a bunch of proprietary stuff, but it has vector tools and will allow you to save a PNG with embedded vector data (which only FW will ever see). While geared for early webDev, it was as good with vector as Flash was originally - Not the best, but workable in some situations. I would agree that using Inkscape or Illustrator would probably be easier/better.

Comment: @Scott - but isn't Fireworks' output raster, not vector? That's what I meant.  If the OP wants to edit an EPS, then I don't think it could be output as an EPS with vectors.  It's been years since I used Fireworks, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @BillyKerr I *think* FW could export a vector EPS file (it's been a long time to to be honest). Mostly what I recall is it was essentially the same as Flash.. could do vectors, but not for print work. And, much like Photoshop, EPS/PDF files *may* contain raster fills in vector containers. It was a decent vector editor for web-destined content though, especially if you wanted to *work* with vectors, but ultimately output raster. Question asks how to *edit* the eps, not necessarily *output* an eps. (Maybe I'm wrong `:)` )

Comment: @Scott - Yeah, I'm not installing it to find out - LOL ;)

Comment: .. and, at the time CS5... the (Adobe-purchased) Macromedia products had more robust SVG support than the Adobe counterparts.

Comment: @Scott - yeah I was a Freehand user back in the day. I also did bits and pieces in flash, even a few whole flash websites, when that was a thing!!

Comment: The file has a group which  contains 3 vector paths. They are a circle, the shadow of the road and the road. The road is a compound path; the midline dashes are subtracted from the road shape to convert the dashes to holes. It's trivial to separate the dashes and the full width road to individual shapes - the road will have no more a midline. The midiline becomes to a bunch of separate (curved) rectangles. What kind of division result you expect? Illustrator is not a must. An online file converter transforms your EPS to SVG and you can do vector edits in Inkscape (=freeware).

Comment: @user287001 - there's not even a need to convert to SVG.  Inkscape can open that EPS file just fine. I tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redrawing the curves, tracing the artwork, would be the easiest method in my opinion.

It's been a looooooooong time since I had a system which could run CS5 apps, let alone since I used Fireworks. However, tracing the sides with the **Pen Tool** in Illustrator is fairly straightforward.

[image]

---

**Note** it is **not** necessary to redraw the sides. One *could* easily just copy the artwork then **delete** everything except the path for one side. Then repeat for the other side in the copy.

[image]

This works, but in doing so the *Blend* method below for the centerline will fail due to the construction of the original paths. So you'd have to determine the centerline yourself. (This is why I'd choose to merely redraw the side paths.)

---

Then, with **Illustrator** I merely created a **blend** between the sides to get a center path...

[image]

Then...

- `Object > Expand` the Blend to get that centerline as an actual path and `Edit > Copy` it
- `Object > Path > Join` the bottom and top anchors for one side and you then have a shape for that side.
- `Edit > Paste in Front` to place the centerline again
- `Object > Path > Join` the bottom and top anchors on the *other* side, and you've got a shape for each side...

[image]

I can not remember how to do *any* of this in Fireworks at this point, other than drawing with the Pen Tool.

<sub>(While not Fireworks CS5 specifically, this all uses Illustrator CS6... which is as close as I can get to FW CS5.)</sub>